# PHP script using over 512MB when only processing a few MB array

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, memory, memory-limit

I have PHP running on Ubuntu with Apache. I have a simple script that simply does a query to pull a bunch of latitude, longitude pairs from the database, stores them into an array, and echo's out the JSON.

The array comes out to be about 40,000 elements. An entry in the array looks like this

```
{"lat":"41.951234015","lng":"-87.5317308"}.
```

The query is to a MySQL DB through an MSSQL DB using a linked server, if that is relevant at all.

PHP runs out of memory if I do `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M')`, but succeeds if I do `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M')`.

Why is this script taking up so much memory? An array of 40,000 elements, with each element being no more than 20 characters or so, should only take up a few MB of memory. I'm not doing ANY processing on the array.

**EDIT: here is my code**

```
mssql_query("SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON");
mssql_query("SET ANSI_NULLS ON");

ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
$cbsa='16980';
if(isset($_POST['cbsa'])){
    $cbsa = sanitize($_POST['cbsa']);
}

$zipstrings = get_zipstring($cbsa); //external function that returns two lists of about 500 zipcodes each

$lat_lng = array();
foreach($zipstrings as $zipstring){
  $result = mssql_query("select * from openquery(database, 'SELECT lat, lng from coordinates 
  JOIN with other table....");
  while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result, MSSQL_ASSOC)){
      $lat_lng[] = array("lat"=>$row['lat'], "lng"=>$row['lng']); **CRASHES HERE**
  }
}
echo json_encode(array("coords"=>$lat_lng, "error"=>mssql_get_last_message()));
```

Comment: we can't look for memory leaks in your code with the code

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 why don't you change your username LOL. Scott W: Can you post your code? You may have a loop stuck somewhere.. 40k elements of that size is barely 2MB.

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: I added the code, it crashes in the while loop

Comment: I'd suggest adding some calls to `mssql_free_statement` or `mssql_free_result` - they'll free up the memory used in your queries. Your code will run a query for each zip, and might not be closing the queries again until it finished the whole script.

Comment: @andrewsi, thanks for the suggestion - my comment was misleading. The loop is running on two lists of 500 zipcodes each, so only 2 queries being executed

Answer (score 0):

How much data does that query return ? You have a select* from opendata if that has very large columns and many of them that will be the cause. Your code looks ok to me

Comment: I'm only selecting two columns (lat, lng). The select * is because I have to query a MYSQL DB through MSSQL, so the query is basically saying "select * from (select lat, lng) "

Comment: Why the abstraction ? Why not direct ?

Comment: Due to permissions and security concerns out of my control, I can't query the MySQL database directly, but must go through MSSQL and a "linked server".

Comment: Try it without the inner loop with say 400 mb of memory. See if there is an issue